# MYSQL: 1265 Data truncated for column?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, truncate, mysql-5.7

I have the following `MYSQL` statement:

```
UPDATE `db`.`appointment` SET `timezone` = 'America/New_York' WHERE (`id` = '114');
```

When I run it I get:

```
1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 **Data truncated** for column 'timezone' at row 1 Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1    0.110 sec
```

And instead of the timezone column being `America/New_York` it is saved as `America/Ne`.

How can I ensure that the *full* value is saved and not truncated?

Comment: What is the exact data type of `timezone` field?

Comment: Likely you've got a field that's too small for that data. Tip: Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default "string" field. Don't get stingy and use `VARCHAR(10)`.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, my field was too small. Feel free to answer the question so I can accept answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here (pointed out in the comments by @tadman) was that the `column length` was too small.

It was `VARCHAR(10)`, when I updated the column to be `VARCHAR(256)` it has worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem when trying to Update a column with a value.
Both the Column and value were Decimal.

The reason mine didn't work was because I was formating the value to be updated

E.g.

```
Update Account Set Balance = Format(NewValue, 2)
```

To Solve this I just removed the Formating and just set it to `NewValue`
and as for why I was formatting the value
I was worried about the extra zeros accompanying the data, it was like `100.000000000000` something like this.